# How to play react-native-webview audio while the iPhone is muted?

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, expo, react-native-webview

I'm currently running an Expo project with react-native-webview 9.4.0 installed, and I'm trying to use the WebView to play audio from a local .html file with a custom JS script using the Web Audio API. The audio works fine on the iOS simulator and on an iPhone when not on Silent Mode, but once I turn on Silent Mode it's impossible to get any audio to play.

There seems to have been a couple attempts to fix this issue over the past couple months (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/1218) and (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1140), but even with the most recent version of react-native-webview I still can't get the Web Audio to play with the iPhone muted. I've tried various workarounds from StackOverflow without any success either. Does anyone else have this issue or have a workaround to suggest?